# convert to tuple list nested in a list of list

Tags: python, list, nested, tuples

I need to use `set(myList)` but it's not possible because I have a list of lists. (It gives a not hashable error).

So I decided to convert each element in the list to a tuple. The list is more or less like this:

```
MyList[elem1, elem2, [nested1, nested2, [veryNested1, veryNested2]]]
```

How can I quickly convert everything to a tuple and then back to a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursion

```
MyList = ['elem1', 'elem2', ['nested1', 'nested2', ['veryNested1', 'veryNested2']]]

print MyList

def tupconv(lst):
    tuplst = []
    for x in lst:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            tuplst.append(tupconv(x))
        else:
            tuplst.append(x)

    return tuple(tuplst)


def listconv(tup):
    lst = []
    for x in tup:
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            lst.append(listconv(x))
        else:
            lst.append(x)

    return lst

mytup = tupconv(MyList)
print mytup

mylist = listconv(mytup)
print mylist
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
def lol_to_tuple(lol):
    return tuple(el if type(el) is not list 
                    else lol_to_tuple(el) 
                 for el in lol)
```

To go back, just replace tuple with list:

```
def tuples_to_lol(tuples):
    return list(el if type(el) is not tuple 
                   else tuples_to_lol(el) 
                for el in tuples)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I've seen this kind of problem before. I solved it by using recursion (on the assumption that the final element is the next level, and that I knew how deep the recursion needed to go to split it up.

Having said that, I think it might be better to ask if you were given the list in that format or if you made it like that through some process? That might help us avoid some unnecessary head-bashing.

Comment: the bad new is that they give me the list in this format, the good new is that it is definetly structured in that way so I'm sure it won't go deeper.

Comment: Hmm, okay so this is kind of hacky but why not use:

yourArray = [elem1, elem2, [nested1, nested2, [veryNested1, veryNested2]]]

last =yourArray[3][3]
second = yourArray[3] 
first = yourArray[0:1] (or something similar, I don't remember string splicing well anymore)

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten your list with:

```
In [1]: from compiler.ast import flatten
In [2]: flatten([1, 2, [11, 12, [21, 22]]])
Out[2]: [1, 2, 11, 12, 21, 22]
```

And then use set(myList)